# Password is not defined in Graphql & Node

Tags: node.js, graphql

I am trying to create a login function with GraphQL and node. I have gotten the sign up to work but when querying the login function it says the password is not defined.

the AuthType

```
const AuthType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Auth',
    fields: () => ({
        userId: {type: GraphQLString},
        username: {type: GraphQLString},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
    })
});
```

This holds data I am expecting back.

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObectType({
  login: {
    type: AuthType,
    args: {
      password: {
        type: GraphQLString
      },
      email: {
        type: GraphQLString
      }
    },
    resolve(parent, args) {
      return User.findOne({
          email: args.email
        })
        .then(user => {
          const isEqual = new Promise(bcrypt.compare(password, args.password));
          if (!isEqual) {
            throw new Error('Password is incorrect!');
          }

        }).then(result => {
          return {
            userId: result.id,
            username: result.username
          };
        }).catch(err => {
          throw err
        });
    }
  }
});
```

This is the logic to check data, thanks.

schema.js

```
 const graphql = require('graphql');
    const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

    const {GraphQLObjectType, 
       GraphQLInt,
       GraphQLString,
       GraphQLSchema, 
       GraphQLID, 
       GraphQLList, 
       GraphQLNonNull } = graphql;

    const User = require('../models/user');
    const Event = require('../models/event');
```

The User type defines what data from the user we would like to store.

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        firstname: {type: GraphQLString},
        lastname: {type: GraphQLString},
        username: {type: GraphQLString},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        password: {type: GraphQLString},
        location: {type: GraphQLString},
        about: {type: GraphQLString},
        gender: {type: GraphQLString},
        yob: {type: GraphQLString},      //Year of Birth;
        events: {
            type: new GraphQLList(EventType),
            resolve(parent, args){
            //  return _.filter(events, {userId: parent.id});
                return Event.find({creator: parent.id});
            }
        }


    })
});
```

The Login function still doesn't recognize the password input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using args in the resolve function, I used {email,  password}.

```
        const RootQuery = new GraphQLObectType({
              login: {
                    type: AuthType,
                    args: {
                           password: {
                                 type: GraphQLString
                            },
                          email: {
                                 type: GraphQLString
                                      }
                         },
              resolve(parent, {email, password }) {
                   return User.findOne({
                        email: email
                   })
                    .then(user => {
                     const isEqual = bcrypt. compare(
                            password, user.password));
                      if (!isEqual) {
                           throw new Error('Password is incorrect!');
                       }

                    }).then(result => {
            return {
              userId: result.id,
             username: result.username
            };
          }).catch(err => {
             throw err
          });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining the password field in your `AuthType`, I guess you should do something like:

```
const AuthType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Auth',
    fields: () => ({
        userId: {type: GraphQLString},
        username: {type: GraphQLString},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        password: {type: GraphQLString},
    })
});
```

Also, you have a spelling mistake in this line:

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObectType({
```

It should be `GraphQLObjectType` instead of `GraphQLObectType`

Also, in this line:

`const isEqual = new Promise(bcrypt.compare(password, args.password));`

Probably you are getting the error there, as `password` is not defined in the code. You probably want to do `user.password`?

Comment: Corrections noted. It still doesn't work when it's included in the AuthType.

Comment: What are you exactly using to generate that code? because I haven't used those GraphQLObjectType before

Comment: Generate how? .

Comment: where are you getting the GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString.. from?

Comment: From graphql. After it is required. Const { graphQLString } = graphql

Comment: I don't think I can do much more if you don't provide more info or a way to reproduce it. sorry